# When I use useNavigate to back previous page I need to click back btn twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When I navigate a URL using `useNavigate` or `useSearchParams`. Then to back the previous page I have to click twice on the back button. I want it when I click once it goes to the previous page.

```js
let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

<label
  htmlFor="featured"
  onClick={() => setSearchParams({ sort: "featured" })}
>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" id="featured" />
  <span>featured</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with this specific code. Are you saying that clicking this "featured" label text issues ***two*** navigation actions and that you need to click a back button twice to get back to the page you were on previously? What debugging have you done to see why this might be the case?

Answer (score -1):

you are using a `useEffect` hook or some kind of logic somewhere else that is changing the **search params** again, just comment them and see if it works.
please provide every component that you are using `setSearchParams` inside.

Comment: Yes, I solved this. Onclick in the label tag and input is inside label so it calls twice.